# Apache commons io Tailer : Handle log rotation

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

I am using Tailer to read lines from some log4j log file and write only certain lines into another destination file.

Now I want to rotate the destination file everyday or at least want to delete some old data from the destination file.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't use the reopen parameter, Tailer handles log rotation itself. :)

Sources:

- [Bug about the reopen parameter not cooperating with log rotation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-399)
- [Source code where it handles log file rotation (approximately)](https://apache.googlesource.com/commons-io/+/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.java#433)